# Is there sufficient information to determine how many people are both engineers and MBAs?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> In a group of 500 people, 350 are engineers, 250 are MBA.  Find how many people are both engineers and MBA?

I believe there is insufficient information given in the question.

My teacher gave $100$ as answer, based on $350 + 250 - 100$.

$(A \cup B)$ is not the same thing as total number of people, right?

But, what if there are people that are neither engineers or MBA?

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, yes there is not enough information.  The problem should have also included the stipulation "*All of these 500 people are engineers or MBA (or both).*"  The "or both" is typically understood.  Based on context, the stipulation I suggest could (*should*) be included could be assumed in a problem written like this, especially in the context of the teaching of fundamental counting principles like here.

Comment: The number who are both is $100 \,+$ the number who are neither.  Your teacher may be assuming that there are no people with neither qualification, or may be saying *at least $100$*

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch it wouldn't be redundant at all... that gives us more information... and specifically tells us that $350$ are engineers, that $250$ are MBA, and as a result we can reason that $100$ are both, that $250$ are engineers who are not MBA, and that $150$ are MBA who are not engineers.

Comment: The question was asking you to find $|A\cap B|$, the number who are simultaneously both MBA and engineers, and it follows from inclusion-exclusion principle and a bit of rearranging that $|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B| = 350+250-500=100$

Comment: @JMoravitz Ohhhh you are right, I didn’t properly read the exercise, I thought we were trying to determine the cardinality of the union but we are looking for the intersection. Thank you for bringing this to my attention, I have deleted my original comments